# how can i generate my task randomly using map without disturbing the current logic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I have a dnd game and right now my task are in the order in which the array is defined but I want my  task to be generated randomly not in a particular order

I am using my task component in my column  component and right now using a simple map function in column component which fetch them from initial data in the sequence they are  defined but i want them to be generated randomly how can i do that there that map function anyone who can help

Column Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Task from './task'
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

export default class Column extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Title>{this.props.column.title}</Title>
        <Droppable droppableId={this.props.column.id} type="TASK">
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <TaskList
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              isDraggingOver={snapshot.isDraggingOver}
            >
              {this.props.tasks.map((task, index) => (
                <Task key={task.id} task={task} index={index} />
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </TaskList>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cosider This:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Task from './task'
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

export default class Column extends React.Component {


  render() {
    const shuffledArr = getShuffledArr(this.props.tasks);
    return (
      <Container>
        <Title>{this.props.column.title}</Title>
        <Droppable droppableId={this.props.column.id} type="TASK">
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <TaskList
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              isDraggingOver={snapshot.isDraggingOver}
            >
              {shuffledArr.map((task, index) => (
                <Task key={task.id} task={task} index={index} />
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </TaskList>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

const getShuffledArr = arr => {
  if (arr.length === 1) {return arr};
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return [arr[rand], ...getShuffledArr(arr.filter((_, i) => i != rand))];
};
```

Comment: it give error 
 Line 59:  'getShuffledArr' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: I have updated my answer, make sure you copy everything. @AmishMaqbool

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number in between 0-arr length-1, and keep decreasing it in each iteration, also move the selected value to the end of array in each iteration, doing so you will not select the same element twice

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

let out = arr.map((_, i, array) => {
 let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length-i))
 let ele = array[index];
 array.push(arr.splice(index, 1))
 return ele;
});

console.log(out)
```

```
{this.props.tasks.map((task, index, arr) => (
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length-index))
    let ele = arr[index];
    arr.push(arr.splice(index, 1))
    <Task key={ele.id} task={ele} index={index} />
))}
```